# PLPGSQL Cascading Triggers?

Tags: sql, triggers, plpgsql

I am trying to create a trigger, so that when ever I add a new record it adds another record in the same table. The session field will only take values between 1 and 4. So when I add a 1 in session I want it to add another record but with session 3 blocked. But the problem is that it leads to cascading triggers and it inserts itself again and again because the trigger is triggered when inserted.

I have for example a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE example
(
id      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,name   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
,session   INTEGER
,status VARCHAR(100)
);
```

My trigger function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_block() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$

BEGIN

INSERT INTO example VALUES (NEW.id + 1, NEW.name, NEW.session+2, 'blocked');

RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_block
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON example
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_block();
```

I get error:

```
SQL statement "INSERT INTO example VALUES ( $1 +1,  $2 ,  $3 + 2, $4)"
PL/pgSQL function "add_block" line 37 at SQL statement
```

This error repeats itself so many times that I can't see the top.

How would I solve this?

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE block_rules
(
id      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,session   INTEGER
,block_session   INTEGER
);
```

This table holds the block rules. So if a new record is inserted into the EXAMPLE table with session 1 then it blocks session 3 accordingly by inserting a new record with blocked status in the same (EXAMPLE) table above (not block_rules). Same for session 2 but it blocks session 4.

The block_rules table holds the rules (or pattern) to block a session by. It holds

```
id | session | block_session
------------------------------
1  | 1       | 3
2  | 2       | 4
3  | 3       | 2
```

How would I put that in the WHEN statement of the trigger going with Erwin Branstetter's answer below?

Thanks

Comment: There might be a more elegant solution. Which version of PostgreSQL do you use? Did I understand you correctly that you only want to fire the trigger when `NEW.session` is `1` or `2`, but not for `3` or `4`? And can `session` be `NULL`?

Comment: "into the example table" - which one? Or do you mean the `example` table? "by inserting a new record" - into which of the two tables? The role of table `block_rules` is not clear to me, either. Please clarify.

Comment: Please answer this question: How do you discern auto-inserted rows in table `example` from others? Do only auto-inserted rows have `status = blocked`? And can we then skip the trigger?

Comment: Yes only rows with `status = blocked` are inserted with the blocked session on the `example` table. Isn't the trigger needed to INSERT the next record automatically? The WHEN statement on the trigger is what I can't crack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### New answer to edited question

This trigger function adds blocked sessions according to the information in table `block_rules`.

<strike>I *assume* that the tables are linked by `id` - information is missing in the question.</strike>
I now assume that the block rules are general rules for all sessions alike and link by `session`. The trigger is only called for non-blocked sessions and inserts a matching blocked session.

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_block()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO example (name, session, status)
    VALUES (NEW.name
           ,(SELECT block_session
             FROM   block_rules
             WHERE  session = NEW.session)
           ,'blocked');

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_block
AFTER INSERT -- OR UPDATE
ON example
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.status IS DISTINCT FROM 'blocked')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_block();
```

---

#### Answer to original question

There is still room for improvement. Consider this setup:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_block()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

INSERT INTO example (name, session, status)
VALUES (NEW.name, NEW.session + 2, 'blocked');

RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER add_block
AFTER INSERT -- OR UPDATE
ON example
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.session < 3)
-- WHEN (status IS DISTINCT FROM 'blocked') -- alternative guess at filter
EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_block();
```

#### Major points:

- For PostgreSQL **9.0 or later** you can use a [**WHEN condition** in the trigger definition](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html). This would be most efficient. For older versions you use the same condition inside the trigger function.
- There is **no need to add a column**, if you can define criteria to discern auto-inserted rows. You did not tell, so I assume that only auto-inserted rows have `session > 2` in my example. I added an alternative `WHEN` condition for `status = 'blocked'` as comment.
- You should *always* provide a **column list** for INSERTs. If you don't, later changes to the table may have unexpected side effects!
- Do **not** insert `NEW.id + 1` in the trigger manually. This won't **increment the sequence** and the next `INSERT` will fail with a duplicate key violation.
  `id` is a `serial` column, so don't do anything. The default `nextval()` from the sequence is inserted automatically.
- Your description only mentions `INSERT`, yet you have a trigger `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE`. I cut out the `UPDATE` part.
- The keyword `plpgsql` doesn't have to be quoted.

Comment: What would I do if I had session 1 blocks 3, session 2 blocks 4 etc and I have a table of rules dictating that?

Comment: @Jimmy: Sorry, I can't make sense of that. It's probably best if you edit your original question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

OK so can't you just add another column, something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE example ADD COLUMN trig INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_block() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.trig = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO example VALUES (NEXTVAL('example_id_seq'::regclass), NEW.name, NEW.session+2, 'blocked', 1);
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
 END;
 $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

it's not great, but it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_block() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    SET SESSION session_replication_role = replica;
    INSERT INTO example VALUES (NEXTVAL('example_id_seq'::regclass), NEW.name, NEW.session+2, 'blocked');
    SET SESSION session_replication_role = origin;
    RETURN NULL;
 END;
 $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: I get ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "session_replication_role". I am only allowed limited access to this database and not super user. Is there a way without setting permissions?