# How to implement column value change constraints in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I'd like to ensure that the value of a column may change in a defined way only. Examples are columns containing a state value which must only change according to defined state transitions) or columns which may be set from `NULL` to something only once.

I'd like to avoid implementing these checks on the application layer.

I could not find a solution using regular constraints. Is there another approach to accomplish that or are constraints like this intentionally not supported on the database layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraints can only enforce rules based on current values of a row (check constraint)
 - or referential integrity between current states of related rows in different tables (foreign key constraint)
 - or to a limited extent on current values of all rows in a table (exclusion constraint).

You want to enforce constraints between *previous* state and *current* state. That's typically implemented with a [**trigger**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/triggers.html).
Example:

- [PLPGSQL Cascading Triggers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601025/plpgsql-cascading-triggers/9611203#9611203)

There are *many* example here on SO. [Try a search.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgres]%20function%20%22RETURNS%20TRIGGER%22%20%20plpgsql%20%22create%20trigger%22)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a python script that generates a CHECK constraints based on a desired restrictions. These constraints enforce setting of null columns for each state.

E.g. When I have "Orders" table and an order can have states "Paid" or "Not paid" and lets say there is a column "Invoice_number" of type text. If you would want to update any order to the "Paid" state, the check constraint would not allow that, unless you set "Invoice_number" from NULL to some non-NULL value.

Simple CHECK could look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE orders ADD CONSTRAINT orders_state_paid_check CHECK ( CASE WHEN state = 'paid' AND (invoice_number is null) THEN false ELSE true END);
```

You can check the tool here: https://github.com/Najiva/check_gen

Right now it is working with postgres > 9.4.